# Is there an existing way in google script to check if an A1 notation is in range of a second A1 notation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently writing a function for this myself, could not find an existing function in the google docs.

But I was wondering, this is so standard, there should be a default way to do this.

I simply want to check if an A1 notation is in range of a second A1 notation.

Example pseudo code:

```
var range = "A33";
isWithinA1Range(range, "A3:A"); //returns true
isWithinA1Range(range, "A:A"); //returns true
isWithinA1Range(range, "A33"); //returns true
isWithinA1Range(range, "A30:B35"); //returns true
isWithinA1Range(range, "A1:A20"); //returns false
isWithinA1Range(range, "B:B"); //returns false
```

Is there a default function for this?

Comment: Nope, no standard function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use regex to separate strings and test them individually. Try this sample:

```
/**
 * @return {boolean} Returns TRUE If the given a1Notation is in the rangeToCheck
 * @param {"A1"} a1Notation The range in A1Notation
 * @param {"A1:B1"} rangeToCheck The range in which to check the A1 Notation
 */
function withinRange(a1Notation, rangeToCheck) {
  var input = Array.prototype.map.call(arguments, function(e) {
    return e.toUpperCase();
  });
  var rangeArgs = /^([A-Z]+)?(\d+)?:([A-Z]+)?(\d+)?$/.exec(input[1]);
  var a1NotationArgs = /^([A-Z]+)(\d+)$/.exec(input[0]).map(function(e, i) {
    return i == 1 ? ('  ' + e).substr(-2) : e * 1;
  });
   /* If range arguments are missing(like missing end column in "A1:1"), add arbitrary arguments(like "A1:ZZ1")*/
  rangeArgs = rangeArgs.map(function(e, i) {
    return e === undefined ?
      i % 2 === 0 ?
        i > 2 ?
          Infinity : -Infinity
        : i > 2 ?
          'ZZ' : ' A'
      : i % 2 === 0 ?
        e * 1 : ('  ' + e).substr(-2);
  });
  console.log(rangeArgs, a1NotationArgs);
  return (a1NotationArgs[1] >= rangeArgs[1] &&
    a1NotationArgs[1] <= rangeArgs[3] &&
    a1NotationArgs[2] >= rangeArgs[2] &&
    a1NotationArgs[2] <= rangeArgs[4]);
}
```

The above supports up to 2 letter columns.

Comment: Thanks, I choose your answer because it is vanilla javascript and it is small and clean.

Comment: What is the `Array.prototype.map.call` doing? I get an error like `TypeError: Can't find function toUpperCase in object Range.`. I'm trying to find out what it does and I only come up with "WTF".

Comment: @botenvou It just converts the given argument strings to UPPERCASE. if `"a1","a1:c1"` is given to the function as strings, it'll return `["A1","A1:C1"]` for regex and uniformity. The `TypeError` is probably because you're sending the wrong type as arguments. You should send only strings NOT range Objects. If you have range Objects, get the [range as string](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getA1Notation()).

Comment: I made a stupid mistake, I overwrote the variable I was passing. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably some issues with this code, but maybe it will give you an idea.

```
function isWithinA1Range(a1Notation,a1_Two) {
  var columnRangeOneStart,colmRngOneEnd,columnRange2Start,colmRng2End,columnIsInside,
      rng,rng2,sh,ss;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

  rng = sh.getRange(a1Notation);
  rng2 = sh.getRange(a1_Two);

  columnRangeOneStart = rng.getColumn();
  colmRngOneEnd = rng.getLastColumn();

  columnRange2Start = rng2.getColumn();
  colmRng2End = rng2.getLastColumn();

  columnIsInside = columnRangeOneStart >= columnRange2Start && columnRangeOneStart <= colmRng2End;

  rowRangeOneStart = rng.getRow();
  rowRngOneEnd = rng.getLastRow();

  rowRange2Start = rng2.getRow();
  rowRng2End = rng2.getLastRow();

  rowIsInside = rowRangeOneStart >= rowRange2Start && rowRangeOneStart <= rowRng2End;

  if (columnIsInside && rowIsInside) {

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: This was the way I thought of as "simplest" - I think the fastest is to do `charCode` / string operations, but that would be hardest to do most flexibly.